# How to process string so to keep characters up to last digit?

Tags: javascript, string

Given strings such as `G08a`, `Professor3`, `Obs`...

**How to slice these strings after the last digit, so it returns :**

```
G08a        ==> G08
Professor3  ==> Professor3
Obs         ==> Obs
```

Starting jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dpyqg2mk/

Comment: why slice ... ?

Comment: Keep. I want to keep the part on the left. If you know a better word I'am for it.

Comment: They don't all follow the same pattern in your example

Comment: Corrected. My apologize.

Comment: @HugoLOPEZ see my answer, the only regex you need is `/.*\d/`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex for this.

```js
var ss = ["G08a", "Professor3", "Obs"];

var res = ss.map(s => (/^(.*?\d)\D*$/.exec(s) || [,s])[1]);

console.log(res);
```

This collects all characters up through a digit that is followed by a series of zero or more non-digits that continue to the end of the string. The initial characters and that last digit before the non-digits are captured in a group.

I used `.map()` as a convenience for the demo, and substituted a temporary array when the regex finds no match.

Comment: ```var res = ss.map(function (s) {
  return (/^(.*?\d)\D*?$/.exec(s) || [, s])[1];
});```

Comment: @HugoLOPEZ: Yes, that's how it would look with traditional function syntax, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

**Short and simple:**

```
let str = "foo9bar";
str = str.match(/(.*\d)|(.*\d?)/g)[0]; // str is now foo9
```

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('txt');
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.match(/(.*\d)|(.*\d?)/g)[0];
```

```html
<p id="txt">foo9bar</p>
```

Comment: Your proposal returns `null` for `str="Obs"`. 
Use `str.match(/\d/)? str= str.match(/.*\d/)[0]: str=str;` so it works in all cases.
https://jsfiddle.net/no763Lfa/

Answer (score 1):

You could match the string by using a search for any character foolowd by a digit or any character which are followed ba a non digit or end of string.

```js
console.log(['G08a', 'Professor3', 'Obs', 'abc123def456ghi'].map(function (s) {
    return s.match(/^.*\d|.*(?=\D|$)/)[0];
}));
```

Comment: Since the goal is to go up through the last digit, I think you need to account for something like `"abc123def456ghi"`. The match should go through the `6`, not the `3`.

Comment: @rockstar, i am not convinced, because op question lacks some more use cases to verify the regex.

Comment: True, but the problem description is explicit that it should be the last digit in the string. Anyway, it's worth pointing out so that the OP knows it'll halt after the last digit in the first sequence of digits found.

Comment: @rockstar, i chnaaged the regex. it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find first digit' position in string

```
var str = "G08a";
var match = str.match(/(\D+)?\d/)
var index = match ? match[0].length-1 : -1;
```

Then make substring

```
var result =str.substring(0,index);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer it correctly. Your answer cuts any text before a number. The question was to cut all the text before the last number (including the number).